# Git cherry pick of merge commit requires local resolution - Azure Devops git

Tags: git, azure, merge-conflict-resolution

[image: Branches structure]

I have a structure of the branches like above. When attempting to cherry-pick changes from alpha to beta in a specific scenario, I've encountered a problem.

Changes from story branch nr 1 get approved during pull request in Azure and merged to alpha. Then after passing tests on alpha, cherry-pick merge from alpha branch to beta for these changes is happening without a problem (using cherry-pick button in a pull request that was created for merge of story nr 1 branch to alpha)

Then story nr 2 changes' have a conflict in the pull request in Azure during a merge to alpha branch (changes to the same lines of code as story nr 1). The resolution of the conflict results in a code that is different than what is currently on the beta branch in those lines. I'm met with an error when attempting to cherry-pick merge from alpha branch to beta branch (also using cherry-pick merge option in Azure pull request): "Encountered conflicts when cherry-picking commit. This operation needs to be performed locally."

I use the command line on the beta branch: git cherry-pick -m 1 {hash of the merge commit for story nr 2 changes on alpha branch}. It proceeds to add those changes to the beta without mentioning any conflicts. It just overrides the changes. How can I make sure to get into the conflict mode locally? Why does Azure tell me to solve the conflicts locally if there are none shown when cherry-picking locally?

Answer (score 1):

I have misused the cherry-pick command locally. I was supposed to use git cherry-pick -m 2 commitHash

Instead, I used cherry-pick -m 1 commitHash and it did stuff the other way around. Everything works as intended now.